# Undo "Always trust software from..."?

Tags: windows-10, security, certificate

[Similar to this question](https://superuser.com/q/1454272/405089) (also the source of the screenshot, as I would have taken the exact same thing, almost pixel-perfect), except that I've already been bitten by the problem that it wants to avoid - hastily clicking Install and inadvertently making it permanent - and so I need to undo that permanence.

[image: "Always trust software from [company]"]

Google isn't helping much.  Lots about alternative ways to make it permanent, but none to undo or revoke that permanence.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Re-enabling prompt for trusting a driver in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/175608/re-enabling-prompt-for-trusting-a-driver-in-windows-7)

Comment: @Moab Normally, Win7 and Win10 are similar enough that instructions for one work well enough for the other, but I had a hard time following this one.  I did eventually figure it out though, thanks to [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/820971/405089) (which is not the accepted one) and the first comment to it, posted by wget.  I did not remove anything from C:\Windows\INF like wget said was also necessary, but a completely unneeded "repair" installation did give me the prompt again.  So I think I can call it a success.  Thanks!